# When is it Pythonic/good practice to subclass in Qt

Tags: python, qt, subclass

I understand in the case where custom behavior is required, e.g. an elaborately constructed and operated `QGraphicsScene` for example, subclassing the `QObject` in question is something of a no-brainer reasonable course of action.

However, what if you want to subclass simply for the purpose of code cleanliness. For example, if I have a `QDockWidget` that requires say dozens of widgets and layouts to be added to it, I can certainly create the `QDockWidget` first and then execute all of the code on that instance necessary to gussy it up. Or, I could also provide all of that UI build code inside of a subclassed `QDockWidget` instance, so that in the main application code I simply need to only create an instance of my "custom" `QDockWidget` and move on. This makes the main application code much cleaner.

Is this a misuse of the purpose of subclassing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, it's not a misuse!
Logically, subclassing is intended to be used to extend/manipulate the functionality of the inherited class.
So, you are doing it right.

Comment: That makes sense to me, thank you for the response! I know I read a comment SOMEWHERE in passing that subclassing should be a last resort instead of an initial design decision and it's for some reason stuck in my brain like a virus haha.